# Return int timestamps instead of datetime

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I was wondering if there is a simple solution to override Laravel/Lumen defaults to return unix timestamps instead of a actual date when returning models.

```
    "mission": {
        "id": 1,
        "start": "2016-01-17 13:57:12",
        "end": "2016-02-17 00:00:00",
        "salary": "1000",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dipsum chipsum, wipsum dodaskipsum wawipsum. Badatiss dum"
     }
```

Now I have to convert date timestamps to unix timestamps all the time, wherever I want to use them(everywhere).

ex:

```
        $result = Mission::all()
        ->map(function ($mission) {
            $mission->start = $this->toTimestamp($mission->start);
            $mission->end = $this->toTimestamp($mission->end);
            return $mission;
        })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [mutate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators) the datetime in your model with a get..Atribute:

```
public function getStartAttribute($date)
{
    return $date->getTimestamp();
}
```

If `$date` is a Carbon object, you should use `$date->timestamp`

Or you could overwrite *all* timestamps on your model:

```
protected function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'U'; //U = Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The thing is they are stored as a Date-time(2016-02-17 20:38:40) in the DB. getDateFormat() will try to createFromFormat('U', 2016-02-17 20:38:40) on a date and make chaos.

Comment: The method I can use is:
`public function getStartAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::parse($date)->timestamp;
}`

For each column needed to return unix-timestamps. It's an alright solution but would have been more satisfied with `getDateFormat()` to work.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's Eloquent returns a Carbon object for date & time fields.

You should be able to use the timestamp property of the Carbon object throughout your code, not sure if this is easier for you, but probably more ideal than modifying the Models to fit your specific use case.

```
$mission->start->timestamp
```

---

It looks like you're converting the Model's properties directly to JSON, so altering the Model (WesleyE's solution) might be the best fit for you.